# iOS contentStretch has been deprecated, how to stretch table cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have some older iOS code which includes a generic custom Composite Subview derived from `UITableViewCell` which overrides `setFrame` and uses `contentStretch` to achieve the resizing.  This is a generic custom Table View Cell class which I can use to display any content I want to in a table row (`UITableViewController`).

contentStretch has been deprecated for a while (iOS6) but I don't see anything on how to rewrite non-image based code which uses contentStretch.  Here is what I have now:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    [super setFrame:frame];

    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    CGSize contentSize = cellContentView.bounds.size;
    cellContentView.contentStretch = CGRectMake(225.0 / contentSize.width, 0.0, (contentSize.width - 260.0) / contentSize.width, 1.0);
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}
```

Update:

It appears that I can get rid of my `setFrame` override and just set the auto-resizing mask in my `initWithStyle` like so:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        cellContentView = [[CompositeSubviewBasedResortCellContentView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.contentView.bounds, 0.0, 1.0) cell:self];
        cellContentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        cellContentView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
        [self.contentView addSubview:cellContentView];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: What is the content you are stretching?

Comment: This is a UITableViewCell, so a row in a table basically.  I don't think the content of the cell matters much here, this is a generic custom cell view class so I could put anything I want to in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use autoresize masks

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

If you paste this in, right click UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth and click "Jump To Definition" you will see the other available options, its pretty straight forward from there.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  It seems I can get rid of my setFrame call entirely!